# Selenium switching windows has varying success rate

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to automate a scenario where an application link opens a new window and I need to interact with that window. I have been successful in doing this however the success rate I've encountered is about 75%, where the other 25% causes problems in that I can't interact with the newly opened window. Here is my current solution.

```
    // Click the link to open the new window
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Link")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000); // Sleep for 1 second

    // Switch to the new window
    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.manage().window().maximize(); // Maximise the new window
```

I have experimented playing around with the sleep timers but these don't seem to help. I am also using the Selenium Internet Explorer WebDriver.

In instances which I can't interact with the newly opened window, the window also does not maximize if that gives any indication of my problem.

Many thanks.

Comment: You are maximizing your window at the end, try this once, maximize your window soon after opening your application(driver.get()) and then set wait time and then copy paste your remaining code

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar I am maximising at the end because I am maximising the window I switch to after it has been opened by clicking the link.

Comment: What exception you get when your script fails? Also problem occurs for any specific browser or with all browser?

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar NoSuchElementExceptions when interacting with a page post switch. I am only using Internet Explorer (the application is IE specific).

Comment: As per exception it seems sometimes element are not located, try using some other locator & set wait time just before the statement which fails usually. Also I assume you have already set Internet Explorer zoom level to 100% manually & have set Enable Protected Mode For All Zones

Answer (score 0):

```
// Click the link to open the new window
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Link")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000); // Sleep for 1 second

// Switch to the new window
for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}

// After switching to the new window.
// wait for some time either use thread.sleep or better to wait on a condition like follows :

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("btnNext")));

// then make the window to maximize   
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ChromeOptions to open the browser always in Maximised mode.

OR

Use this `driver.manage().window().maximize();` as soon as you open the browser connection so that when ever you open/ try to navigate to a new links it gets maximised automatically.

Example for chrome driver as shown below;

```
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Path to chromedriver.exe");  
    driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Comment: I'm not opening a new browser connection though, it's the original browser connection and I'm clicking a link that opens a new window.

Comment: I mean to say when ever you start your WebDriver session include maximize function there it self which works for entire session.